# Material Design parent - child nav for pre 5.0 devices.

Tags: android, material-design

I am porting my app to use material design, however I am clueless as in how to implement the parent to child navigation as described [here](http://www.google.com/design/spec/patterns/navigational-transitions.html#). I have gone through the basics over [here](http://android-developers.blogspot.com.au/2014/10/appcompat-v21-material-design-for-pre.html) but nothing of what I want has been discussed so far.

Comment: Transition API is backported to ICS here https://github.com/guerwan/TransitionsBackport
And useful resource here https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CPxkoe2MraA